# Error opening JDO Meta-Data file after hot redeployment

Tags: jdo, datanucleus, embedded-jetty, maven-jetty-plugin

I have a project with 2 modules `module-b.jar` and `module-a.war`. The first module is a dependency for the second one which I deploy to the `jetty` server using the `jetty:run` goal of the `maven jetty plugin`. I configured the hot redeployment plugin feature by setting the `scanIntervalSeconds` configuration value to 10 seconds.

After running the server, if I modify the jar module and install it to the local maven repository, jetty will detect this change and will restart the webapp (hot redeployment). Until now, everything works as it's supposed to be. I don't have to rerun the server in order to view the new modifications. The webapp is loaded with the new modifications except when I'm accessing a part that uses the persistence mechanism which is `JDO/Datanucleus`, in this case I got this exception:

```
Error opening the Meta-Data file "jar:file:/home/userDirectory/.m2/repository/com/company/module-b/1.0-SNAPSHOT/module-b-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar!/com/company/DomainObject.jdo"
org.datanucleus.exceptions.NucleusException: Error opening the Meta-Data file "jar:file:/home/userDirectory/.m2/repository/com/company/module-b/1.0-SNAPSHOT/module-b-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar!/com/company/DomainObject.jdo"
    at org.datanucleus.metadata.xml.MetaDataParser.parseMetaDataURL(MetaDataParser.java:128)
    at org.datanucleus.jdo.metadata.JDOMetaDataManager.parseFile(JDOMetaDataManager.java:216)
    at org.datanucleus.jdo.metadata.JDOMetaDataManager.loadMetaDataForClass(JDOMetaDataManager.java:719)
    at org.datanucleus.jdo.metadata.JDOMetaDataManager.getMetaDataForClassInternal(JDOMetaDataManager.java:353)
    at org.datanucleus.metadata.MetaDataManager.getMetaDataForClass(MetaDataManager.java:1130)
    at org.datanucleus.store.AbstractStoreManager.initialiseAutoStart(AbstractStoreManager.java:618)
    at org.datanucleus.store.rdbms.RDBMSManager.initialiseSchema(RDBMSManager.java:814)
    at org.datanucleus.store.rdbms.RDBMSManager.<init>(RDBMSManager.java:387)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:39)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:27)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:513)
    at org.datanucleus.plugin.NonManagedPluginRegistry.createExecutableExtension(NonManagedPluginRegistry.java:572)
    at org.datanucleus.plugin.PluginManager.createExecutableExtension(PluginManager.java:300)
    at org.datanucleus.store.FederationManager.initialiseStoreManager(FederationManager.java:168)
    at org.datanucleus.store.FederationManager.<init>(FederationManager.java:70)
    at org.datanucleus.ObjectManagerFactoryImpl.initialiseStoreManager(ObjectManagerFactoryImpl.java:153)
    at org.datanucleus.jdo.JDOPersistenceManagerFactory.freezeConfiguration(JDOPersistenceManagerFactory.java:526)
    at org.datanucleus.jdo.JDOPersistenceManagerFactory.getPersistenceManagerFactory(JDOPersistenceManagerFactory.java:174)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
    at javax.jdo.JDOHelper$16.run(JDOHelper.java:1956)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at javax.jdo.JDOHelper.invoke(JDOHelper.java:1951)
    at javax.jdo.JDOHelper.invokeGetPersistenceManagerFactoryOnImplementation(JDOHelper.java:1159)
    at javax.jdo.JDOHelper.getPersistenceManagerFactory(JDOHelper.java:839)
    at javax.jdo.JDOHelper.getPersistenceManagerFactory(JDOHelper.java:698)
    at myPackage.jdo.impl.LegacyJDOManagerImpl.loadPMFs(LegacyJDOManagerImpl.java:129)
    at myPackage.jdo.impl.LegacyJDOManagerImpl.loadPMFs(LegacyJDOManagerImpl.java:119)
    at myPackage.jdo.impl.LegacyJDOManagerImpl.startTransaction(LegacyJDOManagerImpl.java:340)
    at myPackage.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor.intercept(TransactionInterceptor.java:35)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:246)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.ConversionErrorInterceptor.intercept(ConversionErrorInterceptor.java:138)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:246)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.StaticParametersInterceptor.intercept(StaticParametersInterceptor.java:191)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:246)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.ParametersInterceptor.doIntercept(ParametersInterceptor.java:254)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.MethodFilterInterceptor.intercept(MethodFilterInterceptor.java:98)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:246)
    at org.apache.struts2.interceptor.FileUploadInterceptor.intercept(FileUploadInterceptor.java:252)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:246)
    at myPackage.interceptor.LocaleInterceptor.intercept(LocaleInterceptor.java:36)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:246)
    at org.apache.struts2.interceptor.ServletConfigInterceptor.intercept(ServletConfigInterceptor.java:164)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:246)
    at myPackage.interceptor.ExceptionInterceptor.intercept(ExceptionInterceptor.java:31)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:246)
    at org.apache.struts2.impl.StrutsActionProxy.execute(StrutsActionProxy.java:54)
    at org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.Dispatcher.serviceAction(Dispatcher.java:562)
    at org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.ng.ExecuteOperations.executeAction(ExecuteOperations.java:77)
    at org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.ng.filter.StrutsPrepareAndExecuteFilter.doFilter(StrutsPrepareAndExecuteFilter.java:99)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1157)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.handle(ServletHandler.java:388)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.security.SecurityHandler.handle(SecurityHandler.java:216)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.SessionHandler.handle(SessionHandler.java:182)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.ContextHandler.handle(ContextHandler.java:765)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.handle(WebAppContext.java:440)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.Dispatcher.forward(Dispatcher.java:327)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.Dispatcher.forward(Dispatcher.java:126)
    at org.tuckey.web.filters.urlrewrite.NormalRewrittenUrl.doRewrite(NormalRewrittenUrl.java:195)
    at org.tuckey.web.filters.urlrewrite.RuleChain.handleRewrite(RuleChain.java:159)
    at org.tuckey.web.filters.urlrewrite.RuleChain.doRules(RuleChain.java:141)
    at org.tuckey.web.filters.urlrewrite.UrlRewriter.processRequest(UrlRewriter.java:90)
    at org.tuckey.web.filters.urlrewrite.UrlRewriteFilter.doFilter(UrlRewriteFilter.java:417)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1157)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.handle(ServletHandler.java:388)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.security.SecurityHandler.handle(SecurityHandler.java:216)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.SessionHandler.handle(SessionHandler.java:182)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.ContextHandler.handle(ContextHandler.java:765)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.handle(WebAppContext.java:440)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.ContextHandlerCollection.handle(ContextHandlerCollection.java:230)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.HandlerCollection.handle(HandlerCollection.java:114)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:152)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.Server.handle(Server.java:326)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpConnection.handleRequest(HttpConnection.java:542)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpConnection$RequestHandler.headerComplete(HttpConnection.java:926)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpParser.parseNext(HttpParser.java:549)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpParser.parseAvailable(HttpParser.java:212)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpConnection.handle(HttpConnection.java:404)
    at org.mortbay.io.nio.SelectChannelEndPoint.run(SelectChannelEndPoint.java:410)
    at org.mortbay.thread.QueuedThreadPool$PoolThread.run(QueuedThreadPool.java:582)
```

This can be solved by rerunning the server but that won't be interesting because I will lose the hot redeployment benefits. How can I achieve this without rerunning the server?

Comment: why not include the stack trace of that exception, because it says nothing about what caused the open of that file

Comment: Stack trace included.

Comment: looks like ancient version of code being used there. Half of those classes don't exist in any recent version

Comment: Yes it's true (legacy application). However I think this issue can be solved even though.